# SQLite Database - Update Query

Tags: android, jquery, database, sqlite, sql-update

> Hi there, those 3 "PE_.." i add the values at first on create and those 3 "et.._getText().toString().." gets the new changes by user. Do you get my point? still my application stops as i call update method on db below:

```
controller.update_pw(PE_Desc, PE_Pass, PE_Note, etDesc.getText().toString(), etPass.getText().toString(), etNote.getText().toString());
```

> This is my update method on my database:

```
public void update_pw(String old_description, String old_password, String old_note, String new_description, String new_password, String new_note){
    this.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE PASSWALL SET PW_DESC='"+new_description+"', PW_PASS='"+new_password+"', PW_NOTE='"+new_note+"' " +
            "WHERE PW_DESC='"+old_description+"', PW_PASS='"+old_password+"', PW_NOTE='"+old_note+"'");
```

> I was wondering on commas between "PW_DESC='' , PW_PASS='', PW_NOTE='' WHERE...", is that correct? Need ya help, appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **AND** in **WHERE** clause.
Conditions must be separated by an **AND** operator.

**Edited:**
Another way of Updating values.

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("PW_DESC", new_description);
newValues.put("PW_PASS", new_password);
newValues.put("PW_NOTE", new_note);
SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
db.update("PASSWALL", newValues, "PW_DESC= '" + old_description + "' AND "+"PW_PASS= '" +old_password+ "' AND "+ "PW_NOTE= '" + old_note+ "'", null);
```

Comment: Ohhhkkaayy. Also on the conditions after SET?

Comment: @APX Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     public void update_pw(String old_description, String old_password, String old_note, String new_description, String new_password, String new_note) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String strSQL = "UPDATE PASSWALL SET PW_DESC='" + new_description + "', PW_PASS='" + new_password + "', PW_NOTE='" + new_note + "' WHERE PW_DESC='" + old_description + "' AND PW_PASS='" + old_password + "' AND PW_NOTE='" + old_note + "'";
            db.execSQL(strSQL);
        }
```